# Django views not getting setting variables

Tags: django

Views.py is not picking up anything from settings.py

views.py has import on top

```
from django.conf import settings
```

if tried to run in this file

```
name =  settings.APP_NAME
```

it throws this error

```
AttributeError at /test/app
'_CheckLogin' object has no attribute 'APP_NAME'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have redefined settings elsewhere in the module.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information. Is it possible you're overwriting your settings variable? This suggests that your settings object is a '_CheckLogin' object Try to debug with pdb. Here's a good tutorial: http://simonwillison.net/2008/May/22/debugging/